# Is $\mathbb{R}^n$ connected under the density (Denjoy) topology?

Tags: general-topology, lebesgue-measure, connectedness

Let $\mu$ denote Lebesgue measure and define the function $ d : \mathbb{R}^n \times \text{PS}(\mathbb{R}^n) \to [0,1] $ by $$ d(x,S) = \lim_{r \to 0^+}{\frac{\mu(B(x,r)\cap S)}{\mu(B(x,r))}}. $$

We say $ S\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n $ is open in the density topology if $ S $ is Lebesgue-measurable and, for all $x\in S$, we have $ d(x,S)=\{1\}. $  As the title suggests: is $ \mathbb{R}^n $ connected under this topology?  I think so, but I can't find a proof.

I know $ \mathbb{R}^n $ is connected under the standard topology because it is simply-connected, so one can find a boundary point on the line between two points, one in each interior of the disconnection.  It seems like one ought to be able to mimic this, but the surroundings of the "boundary" point you get can look like $ \{(x, y) : x > 0 \text{ and } | y | < x^2\} \subseteq B(0,1) $ about $(0,0)$.